# Cakephp ver 2 will a validation error on a single field cause the whole saveAll to fail

Tags: cakephp

I have a large associative array with a Model and many hasMany models ready to save with saveAll. The array is formatted correctly and it saves to all the models properly.

However, the data is coming from another system via an API call and there are many records, in excess of 100 plus the hasMany models on top. Currently, as a precaution I am checking if any of the data coming in from the API is duplicated on our system. This is achieved by checking a single field  e.g. "api_input_id". Im trying to improve the performance, as it currently takes up to a minute for 100 records to be checked and written to the DB. The API Get delivers the data in about 4 seconds.

So my question is, if I set the model.api_input_id  to unique and a validation rule isUnique, will the whole save fail and nothing be written to the db, or just the record where the isUnique error occurred? And if its just this one record, what about the hasMany records associated with the failed record?

Thanks